# Tableau server refresh extract not working on scheduled time or at all

Tags: tableau-api

I'm very new to Tableau, so any responses please break them down.

It is thought that my company has a system set up for Tableau-server to automatically refresh data at a certain time of the day, like 4:00 AM, so that the views will reflect current information. The way I understand this set up (I could be wrong), is that in Tableau-online the refresh schedule is set for 4:am as seem in image.

[image]

At 4:am the extract should automatically happen without anyone  doing a thing. The data should be extracted from an Oracle database. When I check the next day to see if the extract worked, it shows the last extraction data was the time I manually clicked the refresh button.

Does anyone know or have suggestions on why the data is not refreshing, or a place I could go to find out?

If there are any other details I could provide let me know, as I said above, I am new to Tableau.

I have searched Google and other articles and have not found a solution. One article suggested add some code. I have no clue where something like that would even go in Tableau-online.

Comment: You should ask Tableau admin guy to setup "Priority" of this extract's refresh. In your image, it says "N/A". Ask them to set it to a number between 1-50 (1 being the highest priority). Hope this may solve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am the admin, and I don't see where I can edit the priority for this refresh schedule.  It's seems like I'm missing some options or something.

Comment: If you refer your attached screenshot then I would suggest to click on the checkbox left to "Full". Then just beside orange color button "New Extract refresh", 'Action' drop down will pop up. There you need to click on down arrow to select 'change priority' (note- these options will be available only when you login with admin access).

Comment: I wish that I could add another picture.  I have tried want you suggested.  When I click on the drop down arrow next to "Actions", the only options I have to chose from is "Delete", and "Change Schedule". I have checked other data sources (like the ones that are not in use) and found that if under the "Refresh Type" it says "Full Refresh" instead of just "Full" then the option to update the Priority will be available. Weird

Comment: May be you better create another extract refresh for this datasource. This extract seems to be corrupted somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Prem. Looking into this situation. I really think it may an authorization issue. Even though my user account has admin privileges, the server that is responsible for automatically refreshing may not. I'm not sure where to go to give a server-machine admin privileges, or if this is even possible.